# How to find the last character of an string and assign it to a char pointer?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, pointers, c++17

I need `Ptr` to have first character of the string and `BufLim` to have last character of the string.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* Str = "Stackoverflow";
    const char* Ptr = Str[0];
    const char* BufLim = &Ptr.back(); // pointer pointing to last character of *ptr

    cout << Ptr;
    cout << BufLim;
    return 0;
}
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: why are you not using `std::string` ?

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is your question?

Comment: You seem to be confused about the differences between `char`, `char*`, and `std::string`. Read about string handling in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)  instead of `const char*` string literals.
Then  you can **easily** have the pointer to the first and the last `char` of the string by the help of member functions [`std::string::front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) and [`std::string::back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) respectively (*given that the string is not empty*).

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;

std::string Str{ "Stackoverflow"s };
/* const */ char* ptrFirst = &Str.front();
/* const */ char* ptrLast = &Str.back();
std::cout << *ptrFirst << "\n";  // prints S
std::cout << *ptrLast;           // prints w
```

---

(Alternatively) in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), you can use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), which is basically a wrapper around `const char*`. Like `std::string`, it has the same kind of member functions [`std::string_view::front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/front) and [`std::string_view::back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/back)

```
#include <string_view>
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

std::string_view Str{ "Stackoverflow"sv };
const char* ptrFirst = &Str.front();
const char* ptrLast = &Str.back();
std::cout << *ptrFirst << "\n";   // prints S
std::cout << *ptrLast;            // prints w
```

Comment: When I written the above code, I'm getting  error: invalid conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, char>::value_type*’ {aka ‘char*’} to ‘const unsigned char*’

Comment: @Meganathan there is no `unsigned` in this code.

Comment: @DrewDormann Its unsigned char const *Ptr = &Str.front(); unsigned char const *BufLim = &Str.back();

Comment: @JeJo Its unsigned char const*